# Set document root to subdirectory, redirect to index .php

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Here's my directory structure:

```
/.htaccess
/public/
/public/.htaccess
/public/index.php
/public/js/main.js
/public/somedir
/public/somedir/.htaccess
/public/somedir/index.html
/public/somedir/js/script.js
```

Basically, I need it to appear that the `/public` directory is the document root, even the vhost has what is here `/` as the document root. So `/public/*` should NOT appear in the URL.

Basically I need `/.htaccess` to either rewrite to an existing file in `/public/` (i.e. I request `/js/main.js` and it serves the file `/public/js/main.js`) or to run `/public/index.php` if no matching file exists.

I need `/public/somedir/.htaccess` to serve a file if it exists in `/public/somedir`, also removing `/public` from the front of the URI, or to serve `/public/index.php` if the uri `/somedir/api/*` is matched, or to serve `/public/somedir/index.html` if neither of those conditions is true.

Here is the source to `/public/somedir/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on
Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/somedir/api
RewriteRule ^ ../index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]
```

Here is the source to `/public/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.*) /index.php
```

And here is the source to `/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1
```

And here is the behavior where => means "request" => "serves":

`/` => `/public/index.php` GOOD

`/nofile` => `/public/index.php` GOOD

`/js/main.js` => `/public/js/main.js` GOOD

`/somedir/js/script.js` => `/public/somedir/js/script.js` GOOD

`/somedir` => `/public/somedir/index.html` BUT redirects to `/public/somedir/` BAD

`/somedir/api/test` => `/public/somedir/index.html` BUT should serve `/public/index.php` BAD

Any insight is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your `public/somedir/.htaccess` should be:

```
Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /somedir/api [NC]
RewriteRule ^ ../index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]
```

and `/public/.htaccess`:

```
DirectorySlash Off
RewriteEngine on

# add a trailing slash to directories
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/public/$1 -d
RewriteRule ^(.*?[^/])$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=302]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1 [L]
```